# SQL Server Преобразование таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста в решении одной задачи. Есть таблица:

```
RowNumber   Value     ColumnName
1           ABC       Name1
2           123       Code1
3           QWERTY    Name2
4           456       Code2
```

ЕЕ нужно преобразовать в такую:

```
Name1   Code1    Name2   Code2 
ABC      123     QWERTY    456
```

Возможно ли это сделать, если да, то каким способом?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть оператор PIVOT.

Выглядеть будет как то так:

```
SELECT [Name1], [Code1], [Name2], [Code2]
FROM
(SELECT Value, ColumnName
    FROM [table]) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
max(Value)
FOR ColumnName IN ([Name1], [Code1], [Name2], [Code2])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотелось бы еще уточнить можно ли сделать этот запрос более универсальным. Что если будут записи Name3, Code3, Name4, Code4 и т. д.?

Comment: Универсальным - только через динамический SQL (т.е. собираете запрос специальным запросом и выполняете через sp_executesql)